# How to draw galactic coordinate grid?

Tags: galaxy, coordinate, map

For my story, I need a galaxy map with star positions in the galactic coordinate system. 2D with a view of the galaxy from above would be enough.

I have gathered data from [Atlas of the Universe](http://www.atlasoftheuniverse.com/index.html) and Wikipedia and continue to search for sources.

The issue for this question is: how to draw a galactic coordinate grid? Preferably using not too complicated computer software.

I have tried to do it in MS Excel graphs, but none is adequate for my purpose.

Comment: "None of it is adequate for my purpose".  What precisely is your purpose ?  It's hard to understand what you want your map to show.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine The result should look like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/Artist%27s_impression_of_the_Milky_Way_%28updated_-_annotated%29.jpg
I want to see how stars are positioned in relation to and how far they are from one another.